# No available Classes problem in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

Olá, quando faço run do meu projeto ele não me deixa porque diz que não tem nenhuma "Available Classes". Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Este problema já me ocorreu devido a importação de um projeto com dependências JRE, enquanto não estava com a versão atual do Netbeans na minha máquina. A remoção completa do Netbeans e do JDK/JRE seguido de suas reinstalações resolveram o problema.